# doubt regarding the base_local_planner::transformGlobalPlan() function

Tags: ros, transforms

I am trying to understand the [base_local_planner::transformGlobalPlan()](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/base_local_planner/html/namespacebase__local__planner.html#a047695bdbc63bda4b4bd5f0f5bd9b585) function.

As per my understanding, the function takes in the `global_plan` (generated by the `global planner`) as an input and updates the `transformedPlan` variable. It does so by transforming the points in the `global_plan` to the `global_frame` (of the `local costmap`) and then removing the points that lie outside the bounds of the `local costmap`.

In particular, I am trying to understand the section inside the first `while` loop - marked by the comments - '**we need to loop to a point on the plan that is within a certain distance of the robot**'.

In this section, we are looping over the points in the `global_plan` until `sq_dist <= sq_dist_threshold`. Shouldn't this cause the first `while` loop to break immediately because the first point in the `global_plan` would be the one that is closest to the bot?

```
bool transformGlobalPlan(
      const tf2_ros::Buffer& tf,
      const std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& global_plan,
      const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& global_pose,
      const costmap_2d::Costmap2D& costmap,
      const std::string& global_frame,
      std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& transformed_plan){
    transformed_plan.clear();

    if (global_plan.empty()) {
      ROS_ERROR("Received plan with zero length");
      return false;
    }

    const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& plan_pose = global_plan[0];
    try {
      // get plan_to_global_transform from plan frame to global_frame
      geometry_msgs::TransformStamped plan_to_global_transform = tf.lookupTransform(global_frame, ros::Time(),
          plan_pose.header.frame_id, plan_pose.header.stamp, plan_pose.header.frame_id, ros::Duration(0.5));

      //let's get the pose of the robot in the frame of the plan
      geometry_msgs::PoseStamped robot_pose;
      tf.transform(global_pose, robot_pose, plan_pose.header.frame_id);

      //we'll discard points on the plan that are outside the local costmap
      double dist_threshold = std::max(costmap.getSizeInCellsX() * costmap.getResolution() / 2.0,
                                       costmap.getSizeInCellsY() * costmap.getResolution() / 2.0);

      unsigned int i = 0;
      double sq_dist_threshold = dist_threshold * dist_threshold;
      double sq_dist = 0;

      //we need to loop to a point on the plan that is within a certain distance of the robot
      while(i < (unsigned int)global_plan.size()) {
        double x_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.x - global_plan[i].pose.position.x;
        double y_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.y - global_plan[i].pose.position.y;
        sq_dist = x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff;
        if (sq_dist <= sq_dist_threshold) {
          break;
        }
        ++i;
      }

      geometry_msgs::PoseStamped newer_pose;

      //now we'll transform until points are outside of our distance threshold
      while(i < (unsigned int)global_plan.size() && sq_dist <= sq_dist_threshold) {
        const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& pose = global_plan[i];
        tf2::doTransform(pose, newer_pose, plan_to_global_transform);

        transformed_plan.push_back(newer_pose);

        double x_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.x - global_plan[i].pose.position.x;
        double y_diff = robot_pose.pose.position.y - global_plan[i].pose.position.y;
        sq_dist = x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff;

        ++i;
      }
    }
    catch(tf2::LookupException& ex) {
      ROS_ERROR("No Transform available Error: %s\n", ex.what());
      return false;
    }
    catch(tf2::ConnectivityException& ex) {
      ROS_ERROR("Connectivity Error: %s\n", ex.what());
      return false;
    }
    catch(tf2::ExtrapolationException& ex) {
      ROS_ERROR("Extrapolation Error: %s\n", ex.what());
      if (!global_plan.empty())
        ROS_ERROR("Global Frame: %s Plan Frame size %d: %s\n", global_frame.c_str(), (unsigned int)global_plan.size(), global_plan[0].header.frame_id.c_str());

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't this cause the first `while` loop to break immediately because the first point in the `global_plan` would be the one that is closest to the bot?

That looks like the intent to me, but I can't tell where `global_plan` is coming from or if it's guaranteed to be sorted by distance. Not quite sure what the point is here, but if you had something like a figure 8 track the position that's closest to you may not necessarily be the one that's next in order if the points are populated along a path.

If that's the case then you could wind up at the crossroads and find yourself basically looping one end or the other of the figure 8 and never actually completing the entire 8.

So, assuming a kind of use case like that, you may expect the next point to be suitable, but if it's not then you'll check all the other points too, just to be sure, and that's what the while loop is doing for you - it's trying the first point, but then continuing to iterate through all of them "just to be sure" none of the other points meet your criteria.